# How to get JVM cache location for current process in linux

Tags: java, linux, caching, process

As we know, each JVM process would create a cache directory. Such like this:

```
/root/.java/deployment/cache/6.0/35

2df4eba3-16182299      2df4eba3-16182299-n    2df4eba3-4678facc.idx
2df4eba3-16182299.idx  2df4eba3-1a176e8d.idx  2df4eba3-654177dc.idx
```

2df4eba3-16182299-n is the cache location.

If I want to get this location in the java code, how to do that?

Comment: In Java proper I don't believe you can except if you are using heuristics; you cannot even get your PID directly. If you could, then you'd walk `/proc/yourpid/fd` and, again, use heuristics. There is one thing though: root? DO NOT run as root unless absolutely required!

Comment: If I usr JNI, I can get the pid, but I just get the java bin location by using readlink("/proc/self/exe",buf,sizeof(buf)); How to use /proc/yourpid/fd?

Comment: Uh, yeah, I forgot about /proc/self :p No need for the PID, then... As to /fd, just read the list of descriptors; it is just a "regular" directory.

Comment: I don't think /proc/self/fd can get the cache location. I wrote a JNI sample and the c code like this:'int fd;
    FILE *fp;
    char path[1024];
    char buf[1024];

    fp = fopen("temp", "a+");
    fd = fileno(fp);
    sprintf(buf, "/proc/%ld/fd/%d",getpid(), fd);
    int res;
    res = readlink(buf, path, sizeof(path));'  I have one question when I wrote the sample, how can I get fd?

Comment: Have you looked at the contents of /proc/*/fd? It's a list of symlinks; you have to read the symlink target and analyze it.

Comment: @fge I can find the one location by using : /root/.java/deployment/cache/6.0/37/15d4bae5-325dd8c0g which is a regular file not a directory.This is not the right location, which should be /root/.java/deployment/cache/6.0/37/15d4bae5-325dd8c0g-n